# i-1 access to a TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I want to go through a map with integer keys that are in the range of 14000-18000. I want to go through them and print the relative difference between them. So if there were three keys `14152` and `14153`, `14159`, the print output would be `0`, `1`, `7`.

I have put my keys and values into a TreeMap, since it stores things in order.

However, with my implementation:

```
int dayCounter = 0;

for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    builder.append(dayCounter);
    dayCounter = entry.getKey();
}
```

I am going through the map but know no way of getting the "previous" entry. If I was using an array I could get the `(i-1)th` value and subtract from `i` to get the relative value. Is there any way to get thie functionality with java maps?

Comment: Your example output (0,1,7) all have them comparing to the first value, not the previous value. If you're comparing to the previous value, you should have `0,1,6` for output, not `0,1,7`. I've prepared solutions for both just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate, you know you have the smallest value first. So I would do something like this:

```
Integer first = null;

for(Integer i : map.keySet()) {
    if(first == null) first = i; // save the first value
    builder.append(i - first);
}
```

Using your example:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
class Eggonlegs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        map.put(14152,"First");
        map.put(14153,"Second");
        map.put(14159,"Third");

        Integer first = null;

        for(Integer i : map.keySet()) {
            if(first == null) first = i; // save the first value
            System.out.println(i - first);
        }
    }
}
```

Results in

```
c:\files>javac Eggonlegs.java

c:\files>java Eggonlegs
0
1
7

c:\files>
```

Now, it's possible that's not what you intended. Perhaps you want the difference between each node, which not what your example shows. In that case, I would leverage the Collections library like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(i == 0) builder.append(0);
    else builder.append(list.get(i) - list.get(i-1));
}
```

Here's an example of that, incase it's what oyu actually intended:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;
class Eggonlegs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        map.put(14152,"First");
        map.put(14153,"Second");
        map.put(14159,"Third");

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(i == 0) System.out.println(0);
            else System.out.println(list.get(i) - list.get(i-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Results in

```
c:\files>javac Eggonlegs.java

c:\files>java Eggonlegs
0
1
6

c:\files>
```

Comment: List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
wow I didn't know you could do this! Awesome.

Comment: APIs are loaded with little goodies like this. You know the whole "good developers learn 90% of what they need in the first week" deal? Well, this is in... like the 92nd percent. I would highly recommend taking a look through the various collections APIs sometime just to see what methods and constructors there are. There's a lot of utility methods that were written just because they're convenient.

Comment: By the way, @eggonlegs - can I infer from your comment that your output supposed to be `0,1,6` after all, not `0,1,7`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Late night basic arithmetic fail. :D

Comment: And I will take a look through collections. Just the native API (?) stuff seems very useful.

Answer (score 4):

simplest and fastest way I think: you can store the last entry in a temp variable, and use it only on next iteration. Don't forget to modify it at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you hold it in a separate variable?

```
//Warning : Notepad coding.
int hold_prev_key = -1;

for(int key : map.keySet())
{
   if(hold_prev_key != -1)
      builder.append(key -  hold_prev_key);
   hold_prev_key =  key;
}
```

Comment: st0le, your answer was great, but I am gonna have to accept glowcoder's answer for completeness and length. :D

Answer (score 0):

I didn't explain my question well. Sorry guys. I wanted a cumulative running total. This is what I did by combining your answers:

```
int hold_previous_key = 0;
int difference = 0;
int running_total = 0;

for (int key : map.keySet())
{
    if (hold_previous_key != 0)
    {
        difference = key - hold_previous_key;
        running_total += difference;
        builder.append(key + " - " + hold_previous_key + " = " + difference + " RUNNING TOTAL = " + running_total + "; ");
    }
    else
    {
        // print 0 for the first date in the data set
        builder.append("first val = 0" + "; ");
    }

    hold_previous_key = key;
}
```